# Vue 3: Conditional v-if on hmtl attributes

Tags: vue.js, conditional-statements, vuejs3

I'm trying to conditional rendering an HTML Elements attribute:

EG:

```
<InputNumber v-model:value="example[index].number" 
     :min="collector.attr[0] ? collector.attr[0] : 0" 
     :max="collector.attr[1] ? collector.attr[1] : 0" 
     :step="0.01"
     style="min-width: 120px;"/>
```

The Problem: the minimum Value of 0 is set (collector.attr[0] = null), but I want eg. that user is able to enter '-100'

The Goal: if the collector.attr[1] is "null" i want to remove the ":min" attribute - resp. only allow this attribute, if there is a minimum value set.

Like so:

```
<InputNumber
     v-if="collector.attr[0]" => then :min="collector.attr[0]" 
 />
```

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: So what exactly are you aiming for? You can have two different `<InputNumber />` with `v-if` and `v-else` conditions.

Comment: I could use it for other attributes as well - so no repeating code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can set a minimum value beyond which a user is not expected to input anything. Something like this

```
<InputNumber :min="collector.attr[0] ? collector.attr[0] : -Number.MAX_VALUE"  />
```

Where [Number.MAX_VALUE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE) is maximum allowed float value in java script, so adding `-` in it makes it negative.